# Scala: Get the id attribute of the last object in a list, or get None if list is empty

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a list of myObjects

```
case class myObject(id:Int)
val myObjects = List(myObjects(5), myObjects(4))
```

I need to get the id of the last object in the type `Option[String]`

I can do this using

```
val lastId: Option[String] = Some(myObjects.last.id.toString)
```

That
's all well and good, but the problem is I need this to work in the case the List is empty. In this situation, I need `lastId` to `None`

I have tried

```
val lastId: Option[String] = myObjects.lastOption.map(_.id.toString).getOrElse(None)
val lastId: Option[String] = myObjects.lastOption.map(_.id.toString.getOrElse(None))
```

and several variations of this but can't get it to work for both lists with objects, and empty lists

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Just remove the `getOrlElse(None)` from the third option, let the types guide you. Also it seems you do not understand how **Option** and `map` works, so it would be good to study them more.

Comment: you are trying to do work the Scala library already does for you. look at the code for lastOption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myObjects.lastOption.map(_.id.toString)
```

testing:

```
List(myObject(5), myObject(4)).lastOption.map(_.id.toString)
//res0: Option[String] = Some(4)

List.empty[myObject].lastOption.map(_.id.toString)
//res1: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for an empty list. When I try this, I get the error, "error: value id is not a member of Nothing"

Comment: @quantumbutterfly; Works for me. (See update.) Note: the empty `List` has to be the correct type.